# Any skeuomorphic/non-flat themes for Ubuntu? (Unity)

Tags: unity, themes, 18.10

I don't know whether a similar question has been asked already, however I am trying to create a custom Ubuntu distribution based on **Ubuntu 18.10** while running **the Unity desktop environment,** *not GNOME.*

I am unable to find any themes which are

1. Compatible with Unity on Ubuntu 18.10 or
2. Skeuomorphic - **not Flat design!**

Can someone please help?

*EDIT* I have searched in GNOME-Look, and the NoobsLab repos, and most themes are incompatible with Unity.

Comment: Where did you search for themes? Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1123739/edit) to include where you've searched so we don't make pointless suggestions.

Comment: DK Bose, I've edited my question to reflect your suggested edits.

Comment: **1**: I suggest you visit https://discourse.ubuntu.com/. Folks there are working on Unity. **2**: Please note that Ubuntu 18.10 will not be supported after July 2019: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29.